# Sharekit Twitter problem in real device

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit on my iPhone app, I used oAuth method, after many problems it worked finally in the simulator, but when I try it on a real iDevice I get this error :

" Request Error
There was a problem requesting authorization from Twitter "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I remember such a problem. I think you can try changing your device's data/time to automatic. I hope it helps.

Comment: I checked, it was already automatic, and even when I changed to manuel the problem persists, and I think it's not suitable to oblige the user to such recommandation. Thank you any way usman.

Comment: I am having this same issue and am wondering did you ever resolve it?